# Oblivious Machines and Input Dependency

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

So I know the Oblivious Turing Machines head position depends on the size of the input word and a number of steps. Can it be modified in such a way that it's not dependent on the size of the input word?

Comment: Don't you see a problem with this definition in case of very large inputs?

Answer (score -1):

According to the [WP article on Turing machine equivalents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine_equivalents#Oblivious_Turing_machines), oblivious machine head position is independent of input and is a function of time instead. To wit:

> An oblivious Turing machine is a Turing machine where movement of the various heads are [sic] fixed functions of time, independent of the input. In other words, there is a predetermined sequence in which the various tapes are scanned, advanced, and written to.

REFERENCES

https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=322123.322138

SEE ALSO

[Head Position Function of Oblivious Turing Machines](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/115432/head-position-function-of-oblivious-turing-machines)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847080/how-does-an-oblivious-turing-machine-work